# checkout svn+ssh with loginname

Tags: svn, console

I want to checkout something out of an repository .. but wenn i type :

```
svn co svn+ssh://URL
```

i get asked for the password.I suppose he uses the username from my console which aren't the same.

So how can i checkout something with svn+ssh  with a different loginname ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

SSH lets you select user in the connection URL:

```
svn co svn+ssh://alabaster@URL
```