# Checkout to remote server using SSH with SVN

Tags: svn, ssh

Does SVN have command to checkout to remote server using SSH?

Normal checkout command is: `svn co file:///var/svn/myrepo /var/www/html/project`

I want to:

```
svn checkout file:///var/svn/myrepo ssh server1 /var/www/html/project
```

Behind all this to only commit once in all different server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This topic might point you in a correct direction: [checkout svn+ssh with loginname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574701/checkout-svnssh-with-loginname)

Here is some more info on SVN+SSH:

Guide from Columbia University: [SVN over ssh HOWTO](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~crf/crf-guide/resources/software/svn-ssh.html)

Another suitable guide: [Subversion access with svn+ssh](https://www.csoft.net/docs/svn.html.en)